# calculus of dp and actual dp doesn't match

Tags: android, dpi, screen-density, density-independent-pixel

i calculated the dp of a device (smallest width), in particular a google pixel 3 (440dpi 1080x2160), using the formula:

```
px = dp*(dpi/160)
```

the result was 392.72, so i created the file `animator-sw390dp-xxhdpi` to handle it, but it turns out that the file isn't applied, instead of it, the file `animator-sw320dp-xxhdpi` is applied.
Using try and error approach i found out that the "true" dp value is 360, in that value the correct file is applied, a hypothetical `animator-sw360dp-xxhdpi`.
if i change 360 to 361, i mean `animator-sw361dp-xxhdpi`, it apply the 320 file again (or 360 if it exists).

So, where is the mistake in the calculus? how can i really calculate the dp of a device given its resolution? and more important how can i know what file will be applied to a file given its smallest width and density without testing files dp by dp as i did?

Comment: Why you have to calculate the px by the resolution? You should do dp*resources.displayMetrics.density in order to have the right number of pixels

Comment: No i don't want to calculate pixels and i'm not talking about code. All this is about XML files. I want an specific XML density file to be applied to my app, and the calculus above is supposed to indicate which file will be applied, a file with the sufix sw390, but it turns out that a file sw360 is applied. This is to manage different screen sizes and resolutions.